# Axios Get reques to Express backend implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, backend

I'm totally fresh at the back-end, right now learning Fron-End but decided to create my own server with Node.js. I installed Express, Cors, and Axios. It seems that it is working since I can see response from API in my terminal but I cannot make a GET request to fire up my machine.

How can I call the GET method? Now data from API is printed in terminal only, on Back-end I get this error:

**GET http://localhost:3002/ 404 (Not Found)

My back-end code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = require('express').Router();
var cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios').default;

const app = express();
app.use(cors())

axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character').then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
});

app.use('/', router);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log(`Port is dummy. At least it started.`);
});
```

Comment: Okay you appear to be making a call at the module scope of your file. That means... it will trigger irrespective of any framework like express. It's like writing `console.log('hello')` -- you could paste that into any javascript file and it may fire, it doesn't really do anything though. Does that make sense? You haven't  written anything related to your framework, it just happens to run when the script executes. Start by returning some hard coded string like "svasune", and once you have that working as expected, replace it with a dynamic response like rick and morty.

Comment: Well you don't define any endpoint, use the router.get method to define a get endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do it :

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = require('express').Router();
var cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios').default;

const app = express();
app.use(cors())

let data;
axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character').then(res => {
    data = res.data;
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(data);
});

app.use('/', router);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log(`Port is dummy. At least it started.`);
});
```

you need to call the router methods, like .get() to define your routes, when you do `app.use('/', router)` it will just use your router, but it will not add a new route to your router, and since it's  an empty router you get a 404

in your case `app.use('/', router);` is the same as `app.use(router);`, you don't need to specify it when it's `/`, it's only useful for things like `/clients` when you want to prefix your routes

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `get` endpoint in your app.
You can do it either using the Express Router:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { data } = axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character');
        res.status(200).json(data)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' })
    }
});

app.use('/', router);
```

Or using only Express:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { data } = axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character');
        res.status(200).json(data)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' })
    }
})
```

Finally, note that `body-parser` is deprecated, you should use:

```
const express = require('express');;
const app = express();

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

...
```